# C: Queue and Memory Limit Excedeed

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I'm a `C` beginner and decided to participate in a small online contest in order to practice.

In the current problem I'm asked to write a queue with a `struct` that responds to the commands `PushBack` and `PopFront`.

The input consists of

- A number `n` (`n <= 1000000`) indicating the number of commands inputs.
- `n` lines. Each line consists of two integer numbers `a` and `b`:

  - `a` is `2` for executing `PopFront`, in which case `b` is the expected popped value.
  - `a` is `3` for `PushBack`, in which case `b` is the value to be enqueued.

If we try to pop from an empty queue then the value returned is `-1`.

The task is to print `YES` or `NO` after executing the last command if the value returned by any `PushBack` during the program execution coincide or not with the expected value.

I implemented a version of this, but after submitting my answer the online judge gives `Maximum-Limit-Excedeed` (in the last test out of `27`).

I was reading about it and this issue may be related to some of these:

1. Using an array or data structure too big.
2. There is an infinite (or too big) recursion in the program.
3. An incorrect usage of pointers (diagnosed as MLE).

I'm not sure what is the problem. It seems to me that in some of the tests the number of addition of nodes is way greater than that of deletions (which means that `1.` takes place in my code) which, in turn, causes the `while` loop in `EmptyQueue` to be too big (`2.` also takes place). I'm not able to spot whether there is an incorrect usage of pointers.

My questions are:

- What am I'm doing wrong here?
- What should I do to fix this?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//===================
//Definitions:

typedef int Item;

typedef struct node
{
    Item item;
    struct node * next;
} Node;

typedef struct queue
{
    Node * front;
    Node * rear;
    long counter;
} Queue;

//===================
//Function Prototypes:

void InitializeQueue(Queue * pq);
bool PushBack(Queue * pq, Item item);
int PopFront(Queue * pq);
void EmptyQueue(Queue * pq);


int main(void)
{
    Queue line;
    long n, i;
    int command, expected, received;
    bool check = true;

    scanf("%ld", &n);

    InitializeQueue(&line);

    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &command, &expected);

        switch (command)
        {
            case 2:
                received = PopFront(&line);
                if (received != expected)
                    check = false;
                break;
            case 3:
                PushBack(&line, expected);
                break;

        }
        i++;
    }

    if (check == true)
        printf("YES\n");
    else
        printf("NO\n");

    // free memory used by all nodes
    EmptyQueue(&line);

    return 0;

}




void InitializeQueue(Queue * pq)
{
    pq->front = NULL;
    pq->rear = NULL;
    pq->counter = 0;
}

bool PushBack(Queue * pq, Item item)
{
    Node * pnode;

    //Create node
    pnode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if (pnode == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Impossible to allocate memory", stderr);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        pnode->item = item;
        pnode->next = NULL;
    }

    //Connect to Queue
    if (pq->front == NULL)
    {
        pq->front = pnode;
        pq->rear = pnode;
    }
    else
    {
        pq->rear->next = pnode;
        pq->rear = pnode;
    }

    pq->counter++;

    return true;
}


int PopFront(Queue * pq)
{
    int popped;
    Node * temp;

    temp = pq->front;

    if (pq->counter == 0)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        popped = pq->front->item;
        pq->front = pq->front->next;
        free(temp);
        pq->counter--;
        return popped;
    }
}




void EmptyQueue(Queue * pq)
{
    int dummy;

    while (pq->counter != 0)
        dummy = PopFront(pq);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact input that triggers the problem?

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Is not showed ):. When looking at the list of test, the first 26 gives `ok` with a mean execution time of 2ms and (I guess) memory usage of 380.00Kb. The last test gives `MLE` with execution time is 98ms and 5.14Mb of memory usage.

Comment: I say you that to manage this kind of problem it doesn't need to manage linked list. You don't need node. It's enough to manage a pointer to a memory area and copy it in a "base pointer". When you push a value you set a value in memory and increase the memory pointer, when you pop the value you decrease the memory pointer and read the value. When the memory pointer is equal to the "base pointer" there's nothing in the stack.

Comment: In PushBack(), looks like you are overwriting values. You need to goto the head/tail of the list and then add newly allocated node.

Comment: @MayurK, the "values" being overwritten are the pointers used to manipulate the list. I don't believe there's anything wrong with that.

Comment: @MayurK I'm not sure if I'm understanding you.  In the part beginning with the comment `// Connect to Queue` the `front` and `rear` pointer point to the same element if the created node is the first one. If it's not the first, then we only have to deal with the `rear` pointer. The current `rear`'s `next` pointer is no longer `NULL`, but point to the new node and after doing that we make `rear` point to the new added node.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Pushback() is always called with "&line". So when it is called for the second time, it overwrites the allocated memory in the first call. It will lead to memory leak. Right?

Comment: @MayurK: no. `line` is the queue structure which simply holds count and head/tail pointers. It's only the list that `line` *points* to that is manipulated.

Comment: You are exceeding the memory limit, because you are using `sizeof(Node)` space (on common 64-bit systems 16bytes) to save 1 `int` (4 bytes). You can decrease your memory usage by a factor of 4 by changing the linked list to an array. Also your program can stop on the first `NO`, it do not need to search for more wrong expectations.

Comment: @mch, that's certainly a *possibility* but, given memory usage on completion is only 5meg, it seems ... less than likely.

Comment: Post the location of the contest, it's possible that you may be misinterpreting the requirements.

Comment: @paxdiablo The contest site is in russian. I translated the best I could.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's actually anything wrong with that code *functionally,* though it could do with some formatting improvements :-)

I *will* mention one thing:

> The task is to check whether the returned value after executing `PopFront` coincides with the expected one. If so, then print `YES`. Print `NO`, otherwise.

I would read this as a requirement on *each* `PopFront`. You appear to be storing the fault condition and only printing `YES` or `NO` *once* at the end.

I'd suggest fixing that as a start and see what the online judge comes back with.

---

This all ignores the fact that it's actually rather difficult to debug code unless you can reproduce the problem. If you can't get the data set from the online contest, it may be worth generating your own (large) one to see if you can get you code to fail.

Once you have a repeatable failure, debugging becomes massively easier.

---

Although it's unlikely, you *may* (as `mch` points out in a comment) be running afoul of limited memory. I consider this unlikely as your own comments indicate only 5meg of space is being used at the end, which is not onerous. However, if that *is* the case, it's probably due to the fact that every single integer has the overhead of a pointer carried along with it.

If you wanted to investigate that avenue, you could slightly adjust the structures as follows (getting rid of the unnecessary `counter` as well):

```
#define ITEMS_PER_NODE 1000

typedef struct node {
    Item item[ITEMS_PER_NODE];  // array of items.
    int startIndex;             // start index (one to pop from).
    int nextIndex;              // next index (one to push at).
    struct node *next;          // next node.
} Node;

typedef struct queue {
    Node *front;                // first multi-item node.
    Node *rear;                 // last multi-item node.
} Queue;
```

The idea is to store *many* items per node so that the overhead of the `next` pointer is greatly reduced (one pointer per *thousand* items rather than one per item).

The code for queue manipulation would then become slightly more complex but still understandable. First off, a helper function for creating a new node, ready for adding data to:

```
// Helper to allocate a new node and prep it for appending.
// Returns node or NULL (and prints error) if out of memory.

Node *GetNewNode(void) {
    Node *pnode = malloc (sizeof(Node));
    if (pnode == NULL)
        fputs ("Impossible to allocate memory", stderr);
    else
        pnode->startIndex = pnode->nextIndex = 0;
    return pnode;
}
```

Next, the mostly unchanged queue initialisation:

```
void InitializeQueue (Queue *pq) {
    pq->front = pq->rear = NULL;
}
```

The pushback is slightly more complex in that it first adds a new multi-item node if the queue is empty or current last node has reached the end. Whether that happens or not, an item is added to the final node:

```
bool PushBack (Queue *pq, Item item) {
    // Default to adding to rear node (assuming space for now).

    Node *pnode = pq->rear;

    // Make sure queue has space at end for new item.

    if (pq->front == NULL) {
        // Handle empty queue first, add single node.

        if ((pnode = GetNewNode()) == NULL)
            return false;
        pq->front = pq->rear = pnode;

    } else if (pq->rear->nextItem == ITEMS_PER_NODE) {
        // Handle new node needed in non-empty queue, add to rear of queue.

        if ((pnode = GetNewNode()) == NULL)
            return false;
        pq->rear->next = pnode;
        pq->rear = pnode;
    }

    // Guaranteed space in (possibly new) rear node now, just add item.

    pq->rear->item[pq->rear->nextIndex++] = item;
}
```

Popping is also a bit more complex - it gets the value to return then deletes the first node if it's now exhausted. That may also entail clearing the queue if the node it deletes was the only one:

```
int PopFront (Queue * pq) {
    // Capture empty queue.

    if (pq->first == NULL)
        return -1;

    // Get value to pop.

    Node *currFront = pq->front;
    int valuePopped = currFront->item[currFront->startIndex++];

    // Detect current node now empty, delete it.

    if (currFront->startItem == currFront->endIndex) {
        // Detect last node in queue, just free and empty entire queue.

        if (currFront == pq->rear) {
            free (currFront);
            pq->front = pq->rear = NULL;
        } else {
            // Otherwise remove front node, leaving others.

            pq->front = currFront->next;
            free (currFront);
        }
    }

    // Regardless of queue manipulation, return popped value.

    return valuePopped;
}
```

Emptying the queue is largely unchanged other than the fact we clear nodes rather than items:

```
void EmptyQueue (Queue * pq) {
    // Can empty node at a time rather than item at a time.

    while (pq->front != NULL) {
        Node *currentFront = pq->front;
        pq->front = pq->front->next;
        free (currentFront);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch. I meant that it prints `YES` or `NO` after executing the last command  if the value returned by any `PushBack` during the program execution didn't coincide with the expected value. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Jazz In that case, as soon as you see a mismatch, you should print `NO`, and exit the program.

Comment: @user3386109  Thanks for your suggestion. If I exit the program at a mismatch that occurred with a `PushBack` at the input number `m`, with `m < n`, then the remaining `n - m` lines with commands can't be entered. I'll think in a way of stopping creating nodes at the first mismatch, but processing the following `n - m` inputs anyway and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

I think is better to use a more simple approach like that in the code I post here.

The code in the following lines doesn't match the input/output required by the contest, but contains a functional and simple approach to solve the problem: A simple stack manager! (if I correctly understood).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int * stack;
int * base;
int cnt;

/* To emulate input file */
struct stFile {
    int n;
    struct stCmd {
        int a;
        int b;
    } cmd[200]; // 200 is an arbitrary value.
} fdata = {
    20,
    {
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {3,35},
        {2,0},
        {3,4},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {3,12},
        {3,15},
        {3,8},{3,18},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {3,111},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {3,8},{3,18},{3,8},{3,18},{3,8},{3,18},{3,8},{3,18},{3,8},{3,18},
        {3,11},{3,13},{3,11},{3,11},{3,11},{3,11},{3,11},{3,11},
        {3,11},{3,13},{3,11},{3,11},{3,11},{3,11},{3,11},{3,11},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {2,0},
        {0,0}
    }
};

int push(int item)
{
    if (cnt) {
        *stack = item;
        stack++;
        cnt--;
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int pop(int *empty)
{
    if (stack!=base) {
        stack--;
        cnt++;
        if (empty)
            *empty = 0;
    } else {
        if (empty)
            *empty = 1;
    }

    return *stack;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i=0,e=0;

    cnt = fdata.n;
    base = stack = malloc(cnt*sizeof(int));

    if (!base) {
        puts("Not enough memory!");
        return 1;
    }

    while(fdata.cmd[i].a!=0) {
        switch(fdata.cmd[i].a) {
        case 2:
            printf("popping ...: %d ",pop(&e));
            printf("empty: %d\n",e);
            break;

        case 3:
            e = push(fdata.cmd[i].b);
            printf("pushing ...: %d %s\n",fdata.cmd[i].b,(e)?"not pushed":"pushed");
            break;

        default:
            break;

        };

        i++;
    }

    if (base)
        free(base);

    return 0;
}
```